# CLion recognizes functions from header file but build fails

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am trying to get into C++ so if I am doing something completely stupid I am sorry.

So I am including GLEW from local folder within the project structure and CLion sees the header file just fine, including all functions GLEW defines. But when I try to build CMake just spits out tons of error about functions not being defined.

For example: `(.rdata$.refptr.glewExperimental[.refptr.glewExperimental]+0x0): undefined reference to 'glewExperimental'`

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/SDL2 ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/glLocal)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_library(glew STATIC IMPORTED)
add_library(opengl STATIC IMPORTED)

set(SOURCE_FILES source/main.cpp)
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test opengl32 glew32 SDL2main SDL2)
```

And I am sure all paths are correct.

UPDATE:

Getting the same error with this config:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(project)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/SDL2 ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/glLocal)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES source/main.cpp)
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(test glew32 opengl32 SDL2main SDL2)
```

Comment: Have you screwed up the order of the libraries?

Comment: I tried swapping the order many times but it didn't help.

Comment: I guess this is related with static linking with *libgcc* (`static-libgcc` linker flag). What if you remove the line with `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`? BTW, you create imported libraries, but never use them.

Comment: Look at edit in the question

Comment: What is the *first* error?

Comment: The one in the question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your errors on my Linux system, but then I don't have anything named glew32 and opengl32. The OpenGL library is called `GL` and the glew library is called `GLEW`. Perhaps you should try these names instead.

Comment: The error you posted is not an error from CMake. It's a linker error. Please accurately paste what you did, and what happened at each step so that the community can help you address your problem.